# Accessing http resources on aws s3 with autorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket with a set of static website resources as shown below:

```
Root-Bucket/
    |-- website1/
    |       |-- index.html
    |       |-- 1_resource1.jpg
    |       |-- 1_resourse2.css
    |-- website2/
    |       |-- index.html
    |       |-- 2_resource1.jpg
    |       |-- 2_resourse2.css
```

All of the objects shown above are private by default.
And I don't want to make above resources being accessible by everyone, only those who have authorized should be able to view index.html with attached resources.
Is there any way serving such static website with authorization?

Comment: Is this a static site? You can't do this, afaik, with a static site hosted in S3 unless you know the source IPs of your users and you whitelist them in an S3 bucket policy. In a non-static site, first thing you need to do is authenticate your users. Once you've done that you can either proxy all of these resources (have all requests go to your webapp that verifies the session is authenticated) or, if you don't like the proxy route, your webapp could dynamically generate S3 pre-signed URLs so the authenticated client can fetch them directly from S3.

Comment: *"only those who have authorized"*... how?  How would the proposed setup know whether someone is "authorized?"  What criteria would apply?

Comment: *only those who have authorized* Can you explain a little more about the rules you're thinking to grant access to `index.html`?

Comment: @jarmod Exactly problem I'm facing, if it's a non-static site I can get it authorized through OAuth token easily, But as I have this static website content I can't code that here.
And about the presigned-url,  I tried that too, the problem with presigned-url is that for resources attached in HTML as relative resource path, I can not access them directly as the presigned-url for those resources contains an `X-Amz-Signature` hash value which is unknown while making public resource request.